# Plot some ordered pairs on the Cartesian plane?

Tags: plotting, graphics, complex

Can *Mathematica* show me a coordinate grid ($x$-$y$ plane) with some ordered pairs plotted on the plane?  Or even better, some complex numbers represented as vectors on the real-imaginary plane?

Comment: Quite probably,  but you need to be much more specific. Please edit the question and add info,  optimally show what you tried already. Sounds like something that could be done using basic `Graphics` primitives.

Comment: @YvesKlett.  Thank you.  The answer provided by David G. Stork was exactly what I needed.  I did not realize ListPlot works on ordered pairs.  Here is what I was ammusing myself with (not that you are or should be interested).  intervalofcoefficients = {-15,  15};maxdegreeofpolynomial = 10; ListPlot[ a:=RandomInteger[intervalofcoefficients, {d}]; 
 f[c_] := {Re[c], Im[c]};  Map[f, Table[
   Total[Table[a[[i]] x^(i - 1), {i, 1, d}]] /. x -> I, {5000}]]] The mapping from the ring of polynomials to the complex numbers by f(p) = p(i) is a homomorphism.  There are some interesting patterns here.

Comment: The code above is no good.  This one works: intervalofcoefficients = {-150, 
  150}; maxdegreeofpolynomial = 10; ListPlot[
 a := RandomInteger[intervalofcoefficients, {maxdegreeofpolynomial}]; 
 f[c_] := {Re[c], Im[c]}; 
 Map[f, Table[
   Total[Table[a[[i]] x^(i - 1), {i, 1, maxdegreeofpolynomial}]] /. 
    x -> I, {5000}]]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Table[RandomReal[], {20}, {2}],
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]

ListPlot[ReIm /@ Table[RandomReal[] + I RandomReal[], {20}],
 AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}]
```

If you want arrows:

```
Graphics[Arrow /@ ({{0, 0}, #} & /@ 
    ReIm /@ Table[
      RandomReal[{-1, 1}] + I RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {20}]),
 Axes -> True]
```

Comment: Note that `ReIm` is new in 10.1, if you have a previous version you can use `{Re[#], Im[#]}&` or `Through[{Re, Im}[#]]&` instead.

Comment: @2012rcampion Ah yes... I'm using 10.1 and the question poser might not be.  Thanks.

Comment: @2012rcampion I always wanted the likewise `Through[{Cos, Sin}[#]]&` . is there something like that in v10?

Comment: @belisarius Maybe in 10.1, but not in 10.0.  If you want to avoid pure functions you can do something like `Map[First]@*RotationMatrix`, but I don't think there's a shorter way.  (There's `ReIm@Exp[I#]&`, but it's not much shorter and less clear.)

Comment: @2012rcampion Oh, yes there are many alternatives. I just wanted a standard WR provided shortcut! Thanks!

Comment: There's no need for the artifice of `RandomReal[{-1, 1}] + I RandomReal[{-1, 1}]`. Since *Mathematica* 6, one may use `RandomComplex`, e.g.: `RandomComplex[1 + I, {20}]`.

Comment: David Park's *Presentations* add-on allows direct plotting of complex numbers, without any need for the user to pull them apart into their real and imaginary parts, by `ReIm` or otherwise. And to draw a coordinate grid: `With[{pts = RandomComplex[1 + I, 5]}, Draw2D[{
   Opacity[0.95], 
   DrawCartesianMap[z, {z, 0, 1 + I}, Mesh -> 10, MeshStyle -> Black, 
    PlotStyle -> White],
   Blue, ComplexArrow[{0, #}] & /@ pts, PointSize -> Large, Red, 
   ComplexPoint /@ pts}, Axes -> True]`
(I'd make this an answer if the question were not on hold.)

Comment: @Dr. belisarius, you can use `AngleVector[]` for that.